# Placing an image at a specific point on a title page

Tags: titles

I am trying to place a logo at the top right hand corner of my title page. I have tried using the titlepage environment, however it continually centers the image. Is there a way to 1) place the image at the top right hand corner and 2) be able to space my text vertically as much as I wish? Even when the image is centered, attempting to move the text vertically is futile.

An example is below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{logo}
\centering
\vfill
{\bfseries\Large
    \vspace{3cm}
    Performance Report
    Blah blah blah
    \vskip2cm
    First Last
}
\vfill
\vfill
\vfill
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you prepared to use TikZ? If so, the `background` package or a simple overlaid picture with the `tikzpagenodes` package. Otherwise, [textpos](http://ctan.org/pkg/textpos) is probably the way to go, though I've never used it myself. (I have used [eso-pic](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic), though.)

Comment: I've added a class so your code can be compiled. Please modify it if it does not reflect your version of reality accurately. And a package ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply would add an `\hfill` before the `\includegraphics`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\hfill \includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}
\centering
\vfill
{\bfseries\Large
    \vspace{3cm}
    Performance Report
    Blah blah blah
    \vskip2cm
    First Last
}
\vfill
\vfill
\vfill
\end{titlepage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

[image: logo]

Overkill, definitely:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,tikzpagenodes}
\begin{document}
\begin{titlepage}
  \tikz[overlay, remember picture]{%
    \node [anchor=north east, inner sep=0pt] at (current page text area.north east) {\includegraphics[width=0.3\linewidth]{example-image-a}};
  }%
  \centering
  \vfill
  {\bfseries\Large
    \vspace{3cm}
    Performance Report
    Blah blah blah
    \vskip2cm
    First Last
  }
  \vfill
  \vfill
  \vfill
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```